# How to match element position with the window scroll position

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to match an elements position with the scroll window's scroll position.

I am getting different values depending on which method I use to get these values.

```
let oStickyButtonsPosition = $('.listing-sticky-buttons').position(); 
// returns {top: 1890.796875, left: 15}

let oBodyPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); 
// returns 1240 at the position where I want to trigger an event
```

I've tried other methods like `let oBodyPosition = $('html').offset().top;` but it always returns `0`

Is there a way to get an element's position to match with the window's offset?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It's not obvious from your question. `$('html').offset().top;` will always be 0, as there is no offset of the html element from the window.

Comment: "Is there a way to get an element's position to match with the window's offset?" - with `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, it's been a bit confusing for me. I finally managed to achieve what I wanted by subtracting the window.height form the element.position then adding the element.height. Very convoluted but it works.